# SharePoint 2010: Excel Services Cache sub-directories randomly missing

Tags: 2010, excel-services, cache

Our client is receiving an intermittent issue (every month or so) whereby the Excel Services cache inside `C:\Windows\Temp\Excel Server\FileCache\GUID\` will having missing sub directories.

When Excel Services is running, it should have directories for:

- Images
- Ranges
- SavedWorkbooks
- Workbooks

On occasion, one or more of these directories are missing, causing Excel Services based reports to be failing:

> Unable to create or access workbook cache at C:\Windows\TEMP\Excel
>   Server\FileCache\0b0faa2c-0612-4045-a910-8a9c2a794cf1\Ranges. Excel
>   Services Application is unable to function without a workbook cache

When this happens I need to manually recreate the directories and the service works again.  However, the issue seems to recur every month or so.

When I restart the Excel Services on the affected machine, it is able to create the directories itself, so I know it's not a permissions issue with the service account.  In addition, the HD has plenty of space left so I don't think it's a disk space issue either.

Thanks in advance for any possible insights into the issue.